# Why is the @Output EventEmitter required in this code example?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding

I'm currently reading about two way data binding in Angular 2 and reading this article.

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

In this article, there is a child component with an @Input and @Output which allows a value inside the component to be bonded to a variable on its parent.

```
export class CustomCounterComponent {

  counterValue = 0;
  @Output() counterChange = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  get counter() {
    return this.counterValue;
  }

  set counter(val) {
    this.counterValue = val;
    this.counterChange.emit(this.counterValue);
  }

  decrement() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  increment() {
    this.counter++;
  }
}
```

parent HTML

```
<custom-counter [(counter)]="counterValue"></custom-counter>
<p><code>counterValue = {{counterValue}}</code></p>
```

So for me, I understand why the @Input is needed - however I don't understand how the @Output counterChange works because it's not even being subscribed by anything on the parent. However, it is necessary to have it there and also have it called counterChange in order to work.

The author of the article says

> The next thing we need to do, is to introduce an @Output() event with
>   the same name, plus the Change suffix. We want to emit that event,
>   whenever the value of the counter property changes. Let’s add an
>   @Output() property and emit the latest value in the setter
>   interceptor:

Why do we need to have the same name plus change suffix? Is this some sort of Angular convention that I'm unaware of? I'm just trying to figure out which fundamental concept I've missed so I can understand how this is working.

I have a plunker of the code here if it'll help.

https://plnkr.co/edit/BubXFDQ59ipxEdnEHWiG?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The @Output() decorator enables the `counterChange` EventEmitter to be used in the Angular event syntax - `(event name)="function()"`.

What stumbles you in this case is the ability of Angular to desugar the `[(counter)]` syntax (called 'banana in a box') to `[counter]="..." (counterChange)="..."`. In other words, Angular will append `*Change` suffix to the property binding value when sees [(property name)] syntax.
I hope this answers the first question.

As to *Why do we need to have the same name plus `change` suffix?*, this is an Angular convention that helps utilizing the 'banana in a box' syntax.

Highly recommend this blog post that explains in details the Angular template syntax:

https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a#4930

Comment: Thank you. That article clarifies things a lot